# Weird Behavior of std::cout

Tags: c++

I have a class for representing nodes in C++ but when printing the output out to with `std::cout` I am seeing a weird issue. Here is the class:

```
class NodeInt
{
    public:
        int value;
        NodeInt* left;
        NodeInt* right;

        NodeInt()
        {
            left    = NULL;
            right   = NULL;
        };

        NodeInt(int val)
        {
            value = val;
            left    = NULL;
            right   = NULL;
        };

        void setValue(int val)
        {
            value = val;
        };

        void insertNode(int val)
        {
            if(val <= value )
            {
                if(left == NULL)
                {
                    NodeInt newNode;
                    newNode.setValue(val);
                    left = &newNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    left->insertNode(val);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(right == NULL)
                {
                    NodeInt newNode;
                    newNode.setValue(val);
                    right = &newNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    right->insertNode(val);
                }
            }
        };
};
```

Here is the main:

```
int main()
{
    NodeInt firstN;
    firstN.setValue(27);
    firstN.insertNode(11);
    firstN.insertNode(29);
    firstN.insertNode(10);

    /**std::cout << firstN.value << std::endl;
    std::cout << firstN.left->value << std::endl;
    std::cout << firstN.right->value << std::endl;
    **/

    NodeInt* n = firstN.left;
    n = (n->left);
    std::cout << n->value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now you'll see I have three std::cout lines commented out. As it is if I run the program right now it will output the correct value of 10. However, if I un-comment the lines it will change the 10 to 2130567168. Picture is showing what I mean:

[image]

What gives?

Comment: More than likely, your `NodeInt` class is broken.  It's not an issue with `cout`.

Comment: The [lifetime warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pEsahV) work currently going on in Clang already catches this. Expect compilers to start aiding with this before too long.

Comment: Your code crashes for me, due to what's mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Note that `std::set` already exists and implements exactly what you are trying to do here;  so you could just use that unless you want to reinvent the wheel as a learning exercise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the two pointers of your `Node` to point to function-local variables in `insertNode()` that will be gone when execution reaches the end of the block they are defined in. The output you get is pure luck.

If you want to do manual memory management you'll have to use `new` and `delete` and your class needs a copy-constructor, a copy-assignment-operator and a destructor. Please read [The Rule of the Big Three (and a half)](https://blog.feabhas.com/2014/12/the-rule-of-the-big-three-and-a-half-resource-management-in-c/) and [The Rule of the Big Four (and a half)](https://blog.feabhas.com/2015/01/the-rule-of-the-big-four-and-a-half-move-semantics-and-resource-management/) (aka The Rule of 3/5).

If you want to have an easier life however you can look up smart-pointers and how to use them and follow [The Rule of Zero](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-zero.html).

Comment: *that will be gone once the function returns* -- It's worse than that.  The local variables used will be gone after the local `if` block has terminated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie just fixed that.

Comment: Note: Typically, it would be better to follow the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and avoid the manual memory management in favor of `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` here. The former will probably be slightly easier to write, in exchange for slightly worse performance.

Comment: @ShadowRanger left a note in the A.

Comment: "Rule of 3 (and a 1/2)" and "Rule of 4 (and a 1/2)" are more commonly known as the ["Rule of 3" and "Rule of 5"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), respectively.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `shared_ptr` doesn't seem appropriate to me for a binary tree implementation

Comment: @M.M: I suggested it only because it removes the need to think about transferring ownership via `std::move` and the like, which you'd need to handle if you were allocating a `std::unique_ptr`, then passing it around a bit before it finally gets attached to the proper place in the tree. Since the graph is acyclic AFAICT, you don't have to worry about reference cycles. Main hitch is the potentially unbounded destructor recursion during cleanup for huge trees with long chains in them, but that's a concern for library authors where scalability it paramount, not toy projects.

Comment: Hi All,

Thanks for the help, I think the fact I was seeing it correctly sometimes was messing me up. I switched my implementation to allocate to the heap to have the data persist out of the local scope and it works now.